# Consider the functions $f(z)=x^2+iy^2$ and $g(z)=x^2+y^2+ixy$. At $z=0$,

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

> Consider the functions $f(z)=x^2+iy^2$ and $g(z)=x^2+y^2+ixy$. At $z=0$,

> (a) $f$ is analytic but not $g$

> (b) $g$ is analytic but not $f$

> (c) both are analytic

> (d) neither $f$ nor $g$ is analytic

My attempt:
for $f(z)$: $u_x=2x=2y=v_y$ and $u_y=0=-v_x$, hence $f$ is analytic at $0$, and for $g(z)$ we have: $u_x=2x=x=v_y$ and $u_y=2y=-y=-v_x$, hence $g$ is analytic at $z=0$.

But if we see the general definition, which implies that if $f$ is analytic at a point $z$ then it is analytic in all points of a neighborhood of $z$ then it follows that neither of them is analytic.

Is my approach correct and what should be the final solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

CR equations have to hold in a neighborhood of $0$, as you have pointed out. The fact they are satisfied at a single point is meaningless.

Comment: If the question was "which of the following is differentiable at $z=0$" then both $f$ and $g$ would have been differentiable right, since they satisfy CR equations at $z=0$?

Comment: No. Go and check the definitions